# Page returns 404 when refreshed, parameter is passed as template

Tags: angularjs, express, routes

I'm having issues with my angular routes when a user refreshes a page, or directly accesses the link in the browser (and not by traversing through links in the site).

*thing.js - angular factory*

```
.factory( 'Things', ['$resource', function ( $resource ) {

    return $resource('/api/things/:name', {
        name: '@name'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
            isArray: true
        },
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
    });

}])
```

*app.js - angular routes*

```
.config( function ( $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider ) {    
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'thing/view',
            controller: 'ThingCtrl'
    });
```

*routes.js - express routes*

```
app.route( '/api/thing/:name' )
    .get( things.all )
    .put( things.update );
app.route( '/things/*' )
    .get( index.partials );
app.param( 'name', things.load );
```

*index.js - express controller*

```
exports.partials = function( req, res ) {

    var stripped = req.url.split('.')[0];
    var requestedView = path.join('./', stripped);

    res.render( requestedView, function( err, html ) {
        if( err ) {
            console.log( "Error rendering partial '" + requestedView + "'\n", err );
            res.status( 404 );
            res.send( 404 );
        } else {
            res.send( html );
        }
    });
};
```

**Error message**

```
Error rendering partial 'things/nameOfThing'
{ [Error: Failed to lookup view "things/nameOfThing" in views directory "/Users/johnsmith/projects/theProject/app/views"]
    view:
    { name: 'things/nameOfThing',
      root: '/Users/johnsmith/projects/theProject/app/views',
      defaultEngine: 'html',
      ext: '.html',
      engine: [Function],
      path: undefined } }
```

I'd expect the refresh to use things/view.html template, but it seems to want to use the passed parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you must have enabled html5 mode for location provider in **app config** like below

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

which sets the base path of your application to '/'.

You can change it to false to use hash based location.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

Comment: This works for me, I did have to change all of my internal links (footer, navbar) to use the '/#/' though. Thanks a bunch @Prasad!